# SocketException: address incompatible with requested protocol

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

I was trying to run a .Net socket server code on Win7-64bit machine .
I keep getting the following error:

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An address incompatible with the requested protocol 
>   was used.
>   Error Code: 10047

The code snippet is :

```
IPAddress ipAddress = Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost").AddressList[0];
IPEndPoint ip = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 9989);
Socket serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
try
{
    serverSocket.Bind(ip);
    serverSocket.Listen(10);
    serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptConn), serverSocket);           
}
catch (SocketException excep)
{
  Log("Native code:"+excep.NativeErrorCode);
 // throw;
}
```

The above code works fine in Win-XP sp3 .

I have checked [Error code details on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740668%28VS.85%29.aspx) but it doesn't make much sense to me.

Anyone has encountered similar problems? Any help?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36150831/2459296

Answer (score 91, accepted):

On Windows Vista (and Windows 7), Dns.GetHostEntry also returns IPv6 addresses. In your case, the IPv6 address (::1) is first in the list.

You cannot connect to an IPv6 (InterNetworkV6) address with an IPv4 (InterNetwork) socket.

Change your code to create the socket to use the address family of the specified IP address:

```
Socket serverSocket =
    new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                        ↑
```

**Note**: There's a shortcut to obtain the IP address of *localhost*: You can simply use [IPAddress.Loopback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.loopback.aspx) (127.0.0.1) or [IPAddress.IPv6Loopback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.ipv6loopback.aspx) (::1).

Comment: IP v4 and v6 have a lot of differences. Since Windows 7, you need to learn both as they have impact on your socket programming.

Comment: any documents/links where these differences regarding to socket programming are listed? they would come in handy

Comment: This is great for localhost, but its not working for me when its NOT local host.  Any ideas?

Comment: what about having this error when calling a partial from mvc on a azure website? ?? i dont get it

Comment: That tiny arrow (↑) is very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Edit C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts and add the line "127.0.0.1 localhost" (if its not there, excluding quotes)

Comment: @LexLi, could you elaborate on why is it not recommended?

Comment: @NikitaSilverstruk, the source code in the question makes unnecessary assumption that it will use IPv4 always. Ata's answer helps fulfill this assumption, and that's why I say it is a workaround only. The best way is to follow the accepted answer.