# Getting no results because SocketException occurred in System.dll

Tags: c#, networking, ip

I am writing an application that retrieves the names and IP addresses of all computers on a given network. This is for technical support to use while remoting into a computer. I'm still developing and only testing on my own network, but when I run it I get no results and this shows up in the output.

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' occurred in System.dll
```

My code is as follows:

```
public List<NetworkComputer> getComputers( string domain )
        {
            List<NetworkComputer> computers = new List<NetworkComputer>();

            DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry( domain );
            DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher( entry );
            searcher.Filter = ("(objectClass=computer)");
            searcher.SizeLimit = int.MaxValue;
            searcher.PageSize = int.MaxValue;

            foreach( SearchResult result in searcher.FindAll() )
            {
                if( result.GetDirectoryEntry().Name.StartsWith( "CN=" ) )
                {
                    IPAddress ipAddress = null;

                    ipAddress = Dns.GetHostAddresses( result.GetDirectoryEntry().Name.Remove( 0, "CN=".Length ) )[0];

                    computers.Add( new NetworkComputer( result.GetDirectoryEntry().Name.Remove( 0, "CN=".Length ), ipAddress ) );
                }
            }

            return computers;
        }
    }
}
```

If I run it without attempting to get IP addresses I get a list of all computers with no issues. It's the IP addresses that are causing me problems.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SocketException: address incompatible with requested protocol](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370388/socketexception-address-incompatible-with-requested-protocol)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this post here

[SocketException: address incompatible with requested protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370388/socketexception-address-incompatible-with-requested-protocol)

This explains the cause to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you are having Connection string set as localhost just change with "127.0.0.1" and the error will be remove.

Comment: why is this the case?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, another instance of this exe is all ready running. When I closed it from task manager then it solved.