# net.Listen() on unix domain socket failed on windows server 2008

Tags: go, windows-server-2008-r2, unix-socket

I'm using domain socket (gRPC) to exchange data between processes, the following code:

```golang
rpcListener, err = net.Listen("unix", "path\\to\\my\\uds.sock")
if err != nil {
    l.Errorf("start gRPC server failed: %s", err)
    return
}
```

will throw following error

```
start gRPC server failed: listen unix path\to\my\uds.sock: socket: An address incompatible with the requested protocol was used.
```

On windows 10, this works ok, is windows-server-2008/windows-7 not support domain socket?

- There are [bugs listing](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#pkg-note-BUG) on golang net package, but only point out `Windows`, not specific windows release.
- MSDN [listed the erorr: WSAEAFNOSUPPORT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/windows-sockets-error-codes-2?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- There also a C# same error thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370388/socketexception-address-incompatible-with-requested-protocol)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [AF_UNIX comes to Windows](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/af_unix-comes-to-windows/)
:

> Beginning in Insider Build 17063, you’ll be able to use the unix socket (AF_UNIX) address family on Windows to communicate between Win32 processes.

So, it looks like that there is no support for it in older versions of Windows like Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 and even in older versions of Windows 10.